# Yii2 json response converts arrays to JSON objects, not json arrays

Tags: json, yii2

I have a yii2 model and relations.
Yii2 response format set to JSON.
I want to return model with its relationships (one-to-many) and so far everything was fine.

However, in this case for one of model relationships JSON response encodes into JSON object {}, not array []. And I can't figure out why exactly? For other relationships it is an array.

Below is var_dump of a model. The problematic relations is `items`

```
/backend/controllers/TasksController.php:181:
object(app\models\Task)[163]
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'Sample dnewsd' (length=13)
      'mode' => string 'onlyads' (length=7)
      'deployed' => int 0
      'start_time' => string '2017-11-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'end_time' => null
  private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'Sample dnewsd' (length=13)
      'mode' => string 'onlyads' (length=7)
      'deployed' => int 0
      'start_time' => string '2017-11-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'end_time' => null
  private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=3)
      'items' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(app\models\TaskItem)[178]
              ...
          2 => 
            object(app\models\TaskItem)[201]
              ...
      'devices' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'deviceGroups' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Here is the JSON return when I edit model:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Sample task",
        "mode": "onlyads",
        "deployed": 0,
        "start_time": "2017-11-16 00:00:00",
        "end_time": null,
        "items": {
            "0": {
                "id": 2,
                "image_url": "/media/lightboxes/pictures/ad_.jpg",
                "duration": 20,
                "task_id": 9
            },
            "2": {
                "id": 46,
                "image_url": "/media/lightboxes/pictures/ad_46.jpg",
                "duration": 20,
                "task_id": 9
            }
        },
        "devices": [],
        "deviceGroups": []
    }
}
```

You can see that items is not a JSON array: `items : {}`

In another action - GET the same model the returned JSON has `items: []`:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "data": {
        "id": 9,
        "title": "Sample dnewsd",
        "mode": "onlyads",
        "deployed": 0,
        "start_time": "2017-11-16 00:00:00",
        "end_time": null,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "image_url": "/media/lightboxes/pictures/ad_.jpg",
                "duration": 20,
                "task_id": 9
            },
            {
                "id": 46,
                "image_url": "/media/lightboxes/pictures/ad_46.jpg",
                "duration": 20,
                "task_id": 9
            }
        ],
        "devices": [],
        "deviceGroups": []
    }
}
```

Here is var_dump for the same model in GET action:

```
/srv/www/erp-ang/backend/controllers/TasksController.php:55:
object(app\models\Task)[163]
  private '_attributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'Sample dnewsd' (length=13)
      'mode' => string 'onlyads' (length=7)
      'deployed' => int 0
      'start_time' => string '2017-11-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'end_time' => null
  private '_oldAttributes' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=6)
      'id' => int 9
      'title' => string 'Sample dnewsd' (length=13)
      'mode' => string 'onlyads' (length=7)
      'deployed' => int 0
      'start_time' => string '2017-11-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'end_time' => null
  private '_related' (yii\db\BaseActiveRecord) => 
    array (size=3)
      'items' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => 
            object(app\models\TaskItem)[178]
              ...
          1 => 
            object(app\models\TaskItem)[184]
              ...
      'devices' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'deviceGroups' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Any clue why could this happen?

Comment: your arrays need to have consecutive indexes starting from 0 (in your first case you have your items indexed `0`, `2` respectively)

Comment: also are you just returning an `ActiveRecord` or are you calling `->toArray()`,

Comment: @csminb. Well, that was not obvious.. Thanks. If you've encountered this before, maybe you know - how would I reindex values of relation array? Since `$model->items` is a read-only property in Yii I can not do something like `$model->items = array_values($model->items)`. Reload the model from db?

Comment: @csminb. Yii2 should call ->toArray() automatically when it encodes an ActiveRecord to JSON. Arrayable interface.

Comment: i'm not sure how it does it internally, but calling it manually might give you better control over what fields/relations you want to show (`$task->toArray([], ['items', 'devices']`) typically relations should not be converted when calling toArray unless you specify [extra fields](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-extra-fields)

Comment: @csminb ActiveRecord or it's parents implement `Arrayable` interface, that's why they can be automatically converted to arrays and encoded to JSON by Yii. In my model I've overrided base `::toArray()` method to include by default `['items', 'devices', 'deviceGroups'] in extra fields. So it works fine. The thing is how to reindex array in relations, after I delete some relations.. For now I've just do another Task::find() to reload model, but it's obviously not the best solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158557/discussion-between-csminb-and-bravik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arrays need to have consecutive indexes starting from 0,
if you need to re-index an already loaded relation you can run

```
$task->populateRelation('items', array_values($task->items));
```